# Format SSD hard disk previously locked with password

Tags: hard-drive, format, password-protection

So few months ago I locked my hard disk from bios, and now I can not remember the password. How can I format hard disk? I tried from KillDisk and he did not let me.

Comment: You locked your computer with the BIOS password, not the disk. We need the exact model of the computer to be able to help.

Comment: To answer the question in isolation; remove the drive and put it into another machine, since the password is in the BIOS.

Comment: Well you can always try to remove the BIOS password by taken out the small battery inside, disconnecting the psu and power it on, so you can deplete any caps on the motherboard. This worked on my old Lenovo that I use in my workplace(It happened by accident), I swapped batteries and in the process the password was lost.